# Split Array at Repeating Object in Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am parsing an `XML` file and creating two `arrays`: one of the XML tags (`$tags`), and the other as the values for the tags (`$values`). As it parses, it adds the tags and values as it goes, when it's done, I `implode` the arrays and put them into a `MySQL` statement:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO everything ($tags) VALUE ($values)";
```

This works fine until I have repeating tags, and then the `SQL` statement doesn't work....

Is there a way to find the first repeated word in the `$tags` array and split it at that word (Keeping the tags that follow it) and also split the `$values` array at the same index that `$tags` was split, so that the information stays in the same order?

So ultimately converting something like this:

```
INSERT INTO everything (AmazonOrderID,MerchantOrderID,ShipmentID,MerchantFulfillmentID,PostedDate,AmazonOrderItemCode,SKU,Quantity,Principal,Commission,AmazonOrderItemCode,SKU,Quantity,Principal,Commission,AmazonOrderItemCode,SKU,Quantity,Principal,Commission,FBA) VALUE ('1','1','D','A','2015','64','OX','1','18','-2','64','WA','1','23','-2','29','WAG','1','49','77','97');
```

Into something like:

```
INSERT INTO everything (AmazonOrderID,MerchantOrderID,ShipmentID,MerchantFulfillmentID,PostedDate,AmazonOrderItemCode,SKU,Quantity,Principal,Commission) VALUES ('1','1','D','A','2015','64','OX','1','18','-2');

INSERT INTO everything (AmazonOrderItemCode,SKU,Quantity,Principal,Commission) VALUES ('64','WA','1','23','-2');

INSERT INTO everything (AmazonOrderItemCode,SKU,Quantity,Principal,Commission,FBA) VALUES ('29','WAG','1','49','77','97');
```

Thanks in advance!...

Comment: To me it appears that you are taking a bad approach based on having a bad DB schema. I would think you would want at least two tables in your DB, one for order -level details and one to capture line items related to each order.

Comment: @MikeBrant I see what you're saying. With my XML file, there are multiple order tags, and within some order tags there are suborders (this is where the multiple AmazonOrderItemCodes come in). Any thoughts for a better approach to writing to MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just base from your "something like".. :)

```
$fields = ['AmazonOrderID', 'MerchantOrderID', 'ShipmentID', 'MerchantFulfillmentID', 'PostedDate', 'AmazonOrderItemCode', 'SKU', 'Quantity', 'Principal', 'Commission', 'AmazonOrderItemCode', 'SKU', 'Quantity', 'Principal', 'Commission', 'AmazonOrderItemCode', 'SKU', 'Quantity', 'Principal', 'Commission', 'FBA'];

$values = ['1','1','D','A','2015','64','OX','1','18','-2','64','WA','1','23','-2','29','WAG','1','49','77','97'];

// i just added this to avoid error produced by: `Undefined offset` error warning
error_reporting(0);

$fields_dup = array();

$values_dup = array();

for ($i = 0, $j = 0; $i < count($fields); $i++)
{
    if (in_array($fields[$i], $fields_dup[$j]))
        $j++;

    $fields_dup[$j][] = $fields[$i];
    $values_dup[$j][] = $values[$i];

    // or maybe you want to add ` and ' make your statement look like:
    // INSERT INTO table (`field1`, `field2`) VALUES ('value1', 'value2')
    // 
    // $fields_dup[$j][] = "`".$fields[$i]."`";
    // $values_dup[$j][] = "'".$values[$i]."'";

}

error_reporting(E_ALL);

// just to show what is produced
var_dump($fields_dup);
var_dump($values_dup);

// while you can also construct your statement in a loop like
for ($i = 0; $i < count($fields_dup); $i++)
{
    $sql_fields = implode(',', $fields_dup[$i]);
    $sql_values = implode(',', $values_dup[$i]);

    echo "INSERT INTO everything ($sql_fields) VALUES ($sql_values) <br>";  
}
```

Output would be:

```
//var_dump($fields_dup);
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=10)
      0 => string 'AmazonOrderID' (length=13)
      1 => string 'MerchantOrderID' (length=15)
      2 => string 'ShipmentID' (length=10)
      3 => string 'MerchantFulfillmentID' (length=21)
      4 => string 'PostedDate' (length=10)
      5 => string 'AmazonOrderItemCode' (length=19)
      6 => string 'SKU' (length=3)
      7 => string 'Quantity' (length=8)
      8 => string 'Principal' (length=9)
      9 => string 'Commission' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string 'AmazonOrderItemCode' (length=19)
      1 => string 'SKU' (length=3)
      2 => string 'Quantity' (length=8)
      3 => string 'Principal' (length=9)
      4 => string 'Commission' (length=10)
  2 => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string 'AmazonOrderItemCode' (length=19)
      1 => string 'SKU' (length=3)
      2 => string 'Quantity' (length=8)
      3 => string 'Principal' (length=9)
      4 => string 'Commission' (length=10)
      5 => string 'FBA' (length=3)


// var_dump($values_dup);
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=10)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => string 'D' (length=1)
      3 => string 'A' (length=1)
      4 => string '2015' (length=4)
      5 => string '64' (length=2)
      6 => string 'OX' (length=2)
      7 => string '1' (length=1)
      8 => string '18' (length=2)
      9 => string '-2' (length=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '64' (length=2)
      1 => string 'WA' (length=2)
      2 => string '1' (length=1)
      3 => string '23' (length=2)
      4 => string '-2' (length=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string '29' (length=2)
      1 => string 'WAG' (length=3)
      2 => string '1' (length=1)
      3 => string '49' (length=2)
      4 => string '77' (length=2)
      5 => string '97' (length=2)

// for the last for-statement

INSERT INTO everything (AmazonOrderID,MerchantOrderID,ShipmentID,MerchantFulfillmentID,PostedDate,AmazonOrderItemCode,SKU,Quantity,Principal,Commission) VALUES (1,1,D,A,2015,64,OX,1,18,-2) 

INSERT INTO everything (AmazonOrderItemCode,SKU,Quantity,Principal,Commission) VALUES (64,WA,1,23,-2) 

INSERT INTO everything (AmazonOrderItemCode,SKU,Quantity,Principal,Commission,FBA) VALUES (29,WAG,1,49,77,97)
```

Is that what you are trying to do?

Hope this is helpful, Cheers! ;)